# How to link two object files by placing their respective sections at different locations?

Tags: c, assembly, linker, bootloader, linker-scripts

I have a bootloader program "boot.asm" which must contains a special word at an offset of 510 bytes from the beginning. And I have a kernel source written in C "kernel.c".

My plan is to call the Kernel (which will be in the second sector of hd) by loading second sector of hard disk from the bootloader program and put it at location 0x8000 in memory.

Now I am compiling both the source files into ELF object files (separately)  into "boot.o" and "kernel.o" and then linking them through a linker and outputting a raw binary file "kernel.bin" .

I want to put my bootloader code starting at 0x7c00 and then at the 0x7dfe location I have to put the special word. Then right at 0x8000 I have to place my kernel code. i.e I want to put respective sections of both the object files at different locations.

This is my failed attempt.

```
ENTRY(boot)
OUTPUT_FORMAT("binary")

SECTIONS{
  . = 0x7c00;
  .text :
  {
    *(.boot)
  }

  .sig : AT(0x7dfe){
     SHORT(0xaa55);
  }

  . = 0x8000;

  .text :
  {
    kernel.o(.text)
  }

  .rodata :
  {
    kernel.o(.rodata)
  }

  .data :
  {
    kernel.o(.data)
  }

  .bss :
  {
    kernel.o(.bss)
  }

}
```

What I have understood is that an executable cannot have a section more than once.

I have limited knowledge about low level programming.

How do I solve this problem.
Thankyou.

Comment: The usual solution is to put the 0xAA55 magic number in the bootsector object.

Comment: Ross Ridge, Not only that, but I also want the kernel to load at location 0x8000, which I forgot to mention in the question (now edited).

Comment: One other thing you might consider doing is using the linker script to compute the number sectors the kernel takes and using those values in boot.asm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to fix two things, don't split the `.text` output section, and use `AT()` to place the kernel immediately after the boot sector in the output binary while keeping its address at 0x8000.  For example, a linker script something like this should work:

```
ENTRY(boot)
OUTPUT_FORMAT("binary")

SECTIONS {
  . = 0x7c00;
  .boot :
  {
    *(.boot)
  }

  . = 0x7dfe;
  .sig : {
     SHORT(0xaa55);
  }

  . = 0x8000;
  .kernel : AT(0x7e00)  /* place immediately after the boot sector */
  {
    *(.text)
    *(.rodata)
    *(.data)
    _bss_start = .;
    *(.bss)
    *(COMMON)
    _bss_end = .;
  }
  kernel_sectors = (SIZEOF(.kernel) + 511) / 512;

  /DISCARD/ : {
        *(.eh_frame)
  }
}
```

I've added some stuff to handle sections you'll see in GCC compiled object files. The `_bss_start` and `_bss_end` symbols can be used to zero out the `.bss` section, and per Michael Petch's suggestion the `kernel_sector` symbol is set to the length of the kernel in 512 byte sectors.